# How-to read details of a certificate using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am trying to decode and get information on a certificate using PowerShell. I want to be able to have a variable $Cert and then pull information about the certificate i.e.

```
$Cert.Subject
$Cert.Issuer
$Cert.ValidFrom
$Cert.ValidTo
```

I have the certificate as a variable.

```
$Cert = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Content Here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

From reading Blogs etc. I am using the following to convert it.

## Decode the Base64 content into a byte array

```
$CertificateBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Cert)
```

**Error - MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."
**

I've tried to see if there are hidden characters etc.

I did make some progress when I removed the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- & -----END CERTIFICATE----- from the $Cert variable

I run the command again

## Decode the Base64 content into a byte array

```
$CertificateBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Cert) and it completes. 

$CertificateBytes
```

just contains a list of numbers.

Then run the following.

## Create an X.509 certificate object from the byte array

```
$certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2`
`$certificate.Import($certificateBytes)
```

Error - MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Import" with "1" argument(s): "X509Certificate is immutable on this platform. Use the equivalent constructor instead."

Tried

```
$certificate= New-Object -TypeName system.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertificateBytes)
```

Error - New-Object: Cannot find an overload for "X509Certificate2" and the argument count: "1608".

```
$certificateBytes.Count
```

= 1608

I am now wondering if this is at all possible as I seem to be hitting a roadblock with every step.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the cert as plain text, you have to convert into bytes first, then you can use one of the constructors:

```
$text = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Content Here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($text)
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($bytes)
```

Then access the properties you requested like this:

```
$cert.Subject
$cert.Issuer
$cert.NotBefore
$cert.NotAfter
```

You might also want to call Dispose afterwards:

```
$cert.Dispose()
```

If you have the certificate as a file, you can load it directly, using one of the other constructor overloads.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Nice.  Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the `new` static constructor method directly:

```
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($certificateBytes)
```

... or wrap the argument variable in an array literal when calling `New-Object`, to avoid having PowerShell pass each byte as a separate argument value:

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList @(,$certificateBytes)
```

---

If the certificate file is stored on disk, pass the file path directly to the `X509Certificate2` constructor - it'll take care of all the Base64 decoding for you too:

```
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new((Convert-Path path\to\file.cer))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly also. Thank you!