Issues Establishing Secure WebSocket (WSS) Connection in C# Console App Using WebSocketSharp
Good day,
I am a self-taught developer aiming to expand my knowledge and improve my skills. Currently, I am working on establishing a secure WebSocket (WSS) connection in a C# console application using the WebSocketSharp library. Despite my efforts, I am encountering several issues and would appreciate some guidance.
Goal: Establish a secure WebSocket (WSS) connection between a server and a client using the WebSocketSharp library in a C# console application.
Background:
My goal is to create a Unity project where one Unity instance acts as the server and another as the client. I started by testing the WebSocketSharp library in Visual Studio 2022 using a console app (.NET Framework) for both the client and server. The unsecured WebSocket (ws) connection works, so I implemented it in Unity, resulting in a working Unity server and client, but still using ws. Now, I am trying to upgrade to a secure WebSocket (wss) connection. Below, I focus mainly on the console app implementation.
Current Status:

WebSocket (ws) connection works over the internet using the domain name on both Unity and Console app implementation of client and server.
WSS connection is problematic: In Unity implementation the server doesn't start because of the error without "HMAC is not supported" error, In console app implementation the server does not have error but the client immediately triggers ws.OnClose without ever triggering ws.OnOpen.

Problems:

In the Unity implementation, I encountered the "HMAC is not supported" error, which I tried to resolve using Bouncy Castle but without success.
In the Visual Studio C# console app, the WSS connection starts and immediately closes without establishing a successful connection. "Connection closed: An exception has occurred while connecting.
Error: An error has occurred in sending data."

Environment:

C# Console App in Visual Studio 2022
Unity Game Engine
WebSocketSharp library: websocket-sharp-core(https://github.com/ImoutoChan/websocket-sharp-core)
Windows OS
Router port forwarding for server setup
DuckDNS for domain name
SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt

Client Code:
using System;
using WebSocketSharp;


namespace ClientLast
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://abyza.duckdns.org:50001/Echo"))
                using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://abyza.duckdns.org:50001/Echo"))
                {
                    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
                        Console.WriteLine("Received from server: " + e.Data);

                    ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection opened");

                    ws.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection closed: " + e.Reason);

                    ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);


                    ws.Connect();
                    ws.Send("Hello, World!");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Running");

                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Stack Trace: {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Ended");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}


Server Code:
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace websocketServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //var wssv = new WebSocketServer(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 50001);
                var wssv = new WebSocketServer(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 50001,true);

                // Load the PFX certificate
                var cert = new X509Certificate2("D:\\12. vscode projects\\websocketServer//certificate.pfx", "pass");
                wssv.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificate = cert;

                wssv.AddWebSocketService<Echo>("/Echo");
                wssv.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("WebSocket server started on wss://localhost:443");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error starting server: {ex.Message}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class Echo : WebSocketBehavior
        {
            protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {e.Data}");
                Send(e.Data);
            }
        }
    }
}


SSL Certificate:

Obtained using DuckDNS and Let's Encrypt's Certbot
Certificate files: cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem, privkey.pem
Converted to .pfx using:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -in combined.pem

PS D:\3_apps\5_vscode_projects\website server\sslcert - Copy> certutil -p pass -dump certificate.pfx
================ Certificate 0 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 0:
Serial Number: redacted
Issuer: CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US
 NotBefore: 13/03/2024 8:00 am
 NotAfter: 13/03/2027 7:59 am
Subject: CN=E5, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): redacted
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
No key provider information
Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.

================ Certificate 1 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 1:
Serial Number: redacted
Issuer: CN=E5, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
 NotBefore: 13/06/2024 2:47 pm
 NotAfter: 11/09/2024 2:47 pm
Subject: CN=abyza.duckdns.org
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): redacted
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
  Provider = Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
Private key is NOT plain text exportable
Encryption test passed
CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully.

Other Condiderations:

I used port forwarding on my home router to my laptop to serve the website, WebSocket, and SSL certificate server.
I know the certificate works because I used the fullchain.pem and privkey.pem files in a Python file to run a simple website, which I could successfully open using HTTPS.
To create the .pfx file, I first combined the fullchain.pem and privkey.pem into a single combined.pem file.

Client console output using ws:
Connection opened
Running
Received from server: Hello, World!
Connection closed:
Ended

Client console output using wss:
Connection closed: An exception has occurred while connecting.
Error: An error has occurred in sending data.
Running
Ended

Questions:

What might be causing the immediate closure of the WSS connection in the C# console app?
How can I resolve the "HMAC is not supported" error in Unity for establishing a secure WebSocket connection?
Are there any additional configurations or steps I might have missed in setting up the WebSocketSharp library for secure connections?

Thank you for your assistance!

In client code at end add Console.ReadKey(); so app does not close and you can see the error messages.

Thank you for taking the time to respond to my query. To clarify, there is already a Console.ReadKey(); statement in both the client and server code. The console application itself is not closing; rather, the WebSocket is triggering the ws.OnClose console message. I have also updated the original post to make the problem clearer and included the console output of the error.

Not when you get an exception.  Move the line after the CATCH.

Thank you once again for your assistance. I have revised the post to correctly include "Console.ReadKey();" in the appropriate location. However, the output remains unchanged and provides no additional information that could help us debug the issue. No errors are being caught by the try-catch block.

Are both problems still occurring the way you stated in the posting?

Yes, unfortunately.

The error is occurring in a library because you are not getting "Error starting server: {ex.Message}".  When an error occurs it only gets captured once unless you have in the code (or library) throw.  So error is in one of these two statements : wssv.AddWebSocketService("/Echo");
wssv.Start();  Error message also says "Error: An error has occurred in sending data."  Where is the "SEND" occurring?

The two statements you mentioned, wssv.AddWebSocketService("/Echo"); and wssv.Start();, are both included in the server code. However, there is no error output on the server side; the error is only present on the client side.
The error occurs when the client attempts to connect to the server, specifically during the execution of ws.Connect(); or ws.Send("Hello, World!");.

What encryption mode is in the certificate?  Depending on the encryption mode will determine the reason for the failure.  The certificate may not be valid for the version of Kerberos.  See https://support.pingidentity.com/s/article/Kerberos-Encryption-type-RC4-with-HMAC-is-not-supported

I am aware that the issue may be related to the encryption mode, but I'm unsure about the exact steps to resolve it. That's why I have outlined the process I used to obtain and convert my SSL certificates so that you guys would be able to replicate the error and also find out the encryption mode.

Start by  using powershell to read the contents of the certificate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432685/how-to-read-details-of-a-certificate-using-powershell

I mean I tried to fix it before but didn't work out.

I also added what the certificate looks like above.

There is no root certificate.  So I think this is the issue : https://doc.kerberos.io/enterprise/self-signed/
